# Don't understand 'if product & 1'

Tags: python

I am doing python exercises from '[w3resource](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/python-basic-exercise-150.php)'. The exercise is 'Write a Python function to find a distinct pair of numbers whose product is odd from a sequence of integer values.'.

The code is shown as followed. I don't understand the whole block of "if product & 1". The sign '&' seems set.intersection but not sure. Meanwhile, why do both 'return True' and 'return False' appear? Can anyone explain? Thanks.

```
def product(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(len(lst)):
            if i != j:
                product = lst[i] * lst[j]
                if product & 1:
                    return True
                    return False

print(product([2, 4, 6, 8]))
print(product([1, 6, 4, 7, 8]))
```

Comment: This is bitwise `and`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions

Comment: `product & 1` is a cryptic way of checking if a number is even. It is best to be more explicit: `product % 2`. The second `return False` statment is unreachable, so it is totally pointless.

Comment: thanks, Stephen & Juanpa!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`product & 1` means check whether product is odd, because the last digit of binary representation of an odd number always is 1 while for an even number is 0.

Seems like you don't really know the meaning of &. & is a bitwise operator. Here's how to calculate 5 & 9:

1) transform 5 to binary representation (5)10 = (101)2

2) transform 9 to binary representation (9)10 = (1001)2

3) for every binary digit, & with two 1 is 1 otherwise 0. So

```
    ( 101)2 
  & (1001)2
  = (0001)2
```